# Return (dispatch) not fired

Tags: javascript, api, redux

I am beginner with Redux and this is my code :

**Component : alerteProduit.js**

```
// Map Redux state to component props
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    alertes: state.dashboardDomain.Qualite, //récupération de la liste contenu dans le state (dashboard_reducer -> Qualite)
  }
}

// Map Redux actions to component props
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getAlertes: () => dashboard_actions.dashboard_getAlerteProduit(), //appel méthode action vers api
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AlerteProduit);
```

**dashboard_action.js**

```
export function dashboard_getAlerteProduit() { 
  console.log("fired")
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log("not fired")
    var alertes = Deserialize(storage.get("alertes"))

    if (!alertes) {//si pas d'alertes dans le store local on va les chercher dans l'api
      dashboard_api.getAlerteProduits(dispatch, storage.get("1483")) //la fonction getAlerteProduits() attend l'id du client connecté
        .then((ap) => {
          storage.set("alertes", Serialize(ap))
          dispatch(Get_AlerteProduits(ap))
        })
    } else {//si on a déjà des alertes dans le store local on les renvois
      dispatch(Get_AlerteProduits(alertes))
    }
  };
}
```

**dashboard_api.js**

```
export function getAlerteProduits(dispatch, idClient) {
    return auth_get_dispatch(dispatch, '/api/Produits/GetRappelProduit?idClient=' + idClient)
}
```

You can see in the dashboard_action.js, the beginning of the method is called but not after the "return". Do you know what is wrong in my project ? By the way my API is returning the correct result so the error is not from this side.

Comment: are you returning an object with a "type" key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is in *mapDispatchToProps*.

```
getAlertes: () => dashboard_actions.dashboard_getAlerteProduit()
```

It should be:

```
getAlertes: () => dispatch(dashboard_actions.dashboard_getAlerteProduit())
```

Update:

Also, you need a return inside the arrow function at dashboard_getAlerteProduit:

```
if (!alertes) {//si pas d'alertes dans le store local on va les chercher dans l'api
  return dashboard_api.getAlerteProduits(dispatch, storage.get("1483")) //la fonction getAlerteProduits() attend l'id du client connecté
    .then((ap) => {
      storage.set("alertes", Serialize(ap))
      dispatch(Get_AlerteProduits(ap))
    })
} else {//si on a déjà des alertes dans le store local on les renvois
  return dispatch(Get_AlerteProduits(alertes))
}
```

Comment: @Phobie Updated the answer.